# How to redirect to the login page with BjyAuthorize

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser, bjyauthorize

I want to redirect some pages to the login page instead of page 403.

By default BjyAuthorize redirects everything to a 403 page. Is it possible to configure this behavior?

I found this: [RedirectionStrategy](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/master/src/BjyAuthorize/View/RedirectionStrategy.php). How do I use this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I got it.

With version 1.2.* of BjyAuthorize, you simply add in `config/autoload/bjyauthorize.global.php` :

```
return array(
    'bjyauthorize' => array(
        'unauthorized_strategy' => 'BjyAuthorize\View\RedirectionStrategy',
//      [...]
    ),
);
```

And it will redirect you to the route configured in `vendor/bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize/src/BjyAuthorize/View/RedirectionStrategy.php`

Comment: Ah, looks like the author integrated this strategy into the new version.

Comment: And how exactly you set to what route you want to redirect?

Comment: @Sharikov, the instructions on how to set the route are here:

https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/master/docs/unauthorized-strategies.md

Comment: Is there way to setup RedirectUri in bjyauthorize.global.php? This is how I set Redirection Strategy there:    'unauthorized_strategy' => 'BjyAuthorize\View\RedirectionStrategy'.

Answer (score 3):

Check this UnauthorizedStrategy class by Rob Allen: https://gist.github.com/akrabat/3783912
When using this class you have to configure BjyAuthorize to use it, like this:

```
return array(
    'bjyauthorize' => array(
        'unauthorized_strategy' => 'Application\View\UnauthorizedStrategy',
    ),
);
```

Edit:
Don't forget to add the relevant service manager config to allow the service manager to instantiate the UnauthorizedStrategy object:

```
'service_manager' => array(
'invokables' => array(
            'Application\View\UnauthorizedStrategy' => 'Application\View\UnauthorizedStrategy',
        ),
```

Comment: I've put this code in `config/autoload/bjyauthorize.global.php` with the class by Rob allen in the right place. But it does not seem to work.

Comment: That's right, you have to add the service_manager config part to be able to instantiate it. See edit above in the answer.

Comment: I put both configuration values inside bjyauthorize.config.php and it did the trick. To me, it seems it's more relevant that way :)

Comment: I made this work by also adding the class to the getServiceConfig function in Module.php as a factory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying and I came across this page: https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/issues/24

This way, you can extend the UnauthorizedStrategy.