# Redirect path is using full controller path (redirect for bjyauthorize)

Tags: zend-framework2, router, bjyauthorize

I'm having trouble with redirect using bjyauthorize. I followed this link: [How to redirect to the login page with BjyAuthorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457134/how-to-redirect-to-the-login-page-with-bjyauthorize/17460088#17460088) and is able to get redirect working.

The problem that I'm facing is that the redirect is building a url with full controller path.

```
http://lh/user/login?redirect=/talent/my/Myapp%5CController%5CProfile/index

where my route and controller are below:
route: talent/my
controller: Myapp\Controller\Profile
```

The code for building the redirect string is (edit: posting the full onDispatchError function):

```
public function onDispatchError(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // Do nothing if the result is a response object
    $result = $e->getResult();
    if ($result instanceof Response) {
        return;
    }

    $router = $e->getRouter();
    $match  = $e->getRouteMatch();

    // get url to the zfcuser/login route
    $options['name'] = 'zfcuser/login';
    $url = $router->assemble(array(), $options);

    // Work out where were we trying to get to
    $options['name'] = $match->getMatchedRouteName();

    $matchParams = $match->getParams();

    // [jh]
    // TODO: need to fix this in a smart way
    // have already posted the problem on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461274/redirect-path-is-using-full-controller-path-redirect-for-bjyauthorize
    $newParams = array(
        'controller' => $matchParams["__CONTROLLER__"],
    );

    // [jh]
    // having an index in the url looks a bit unprofessional
    // so, here i'm removing it... code is a bit dirty
    if ( 'index' !=  $matchParams["action"] )
        $newParams['action'] = $matchParams["action"];


    $redirect = $router->assemble($newParams, $options);


    // set up response to redirect to login page
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    if (!$response) {
        $response = new HttpResponse();
        $e->setResponse($response);
    }
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url . '?redirect=' . $redirect);
    $response->setStatusCode(302);
}
```

Here, I added var_dump for the following
$match->getParams():

```
array(4) {
  ["__NAMESPACE__"]=>
  string(14) "Myapp\Controller"
  ["controller"]=>
  string(22) "Myapp\Controller\Profile"
  ["action"]=>
  string(5) "index"
  ["__CONTROLLER__"]=>
  string(7) "profile"
}
```

$options:

```
array(1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(16) "route_my/default"
}
```

I could change the params so 'controller' field is set to 'profile' to fixed this issue. But, I don't think that is the best approach.

Please advice!

Thanks,

Justin

Comment: Can you post the rest of your onDispatchError method?

Comment: Hi Ruben! I have just edit my post with my full onDispatchEvent. Thanks!